# Gradle publishing - add testCompile dependencies to ivy.xml

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, ivy

When I have the publishing section below in my build.gradle I'll get my ivy.xml descriptor file filled with dependencies as desired. So far so good.

Question: How can I archive it so that the publishing task will also add the testCompile dependencies from my build.gradle dependency section to my ivy.xml file?

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
    classifier "source"
}


publishing {
    publications {
        jarAndSources(IvyPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact(sourceJar) {
                type "source"
                extension "src.jar"
            }
        }
    }
     repositories {...}
}
```

Do I need to specify some sort of a configuration?

Comment: Why would you want your testCompile dependencies in your ivy.xml? The whole point of testCompile is that you use it for testing, but don't include it in your runtime packaging. If you want them in ivy.xml, why not move the relevant dependencies from testCompile to Compile?

Comment: We're switching from Ivy/Ant to gradle and we're having a module which is pretty much at the bottom of the dependency tree. This module pulls in Junit and Mockito so that it was available for all other modules through transitive dependencies. I thought that might also be possible if i have it in the ivy.xml built by gradle.

Comment: Just solved it by adding the test dependencies in my common.gradle which every module pulls in :) Thank you RaGe for the Answer!